# Mongodb search multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, meteor

Basically I am searching messages.
I have 2 collections:

- Users
- Messages

Users:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Xuibgsadbgsi35Gsdf",
        "fullName": "User A"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Afstg34tg4536gh",
        "fullName": "User B"
    },
    {
        "_id": "KHJDFhfs7dfgsvdfwsef",
        "fullName": "User C"
    }
]
```

Messages:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "YONgsa793423bD",
        "groupId": "Phsdfyg92345sgb7651",
        "senderId": "Xuibgsadbgsi35Gsdf",
        "message": "Hello there!"
    },
    {
        "_id": "sdgDFGbaofh135df",
        "groupId": "Phsdfyg92345sgb7651",
        "senderId": "KHJDFhfs7dfgsvdfwsef",
        "message": "Hello @Xuibgsadbgsi35Gsdf"
    },
    {
        "_id": "sdgDFGbaofh135df",
        "groupId": "Phsdfyg92345sgb7651",
        "senderId": "KHJDFhfs7dfgsvdfwsef",
        "message": "Hello"
    }
]
```

Now here I want to search: `User A`, so I should get those message in which `User A` is involved in any way, either he is a sender or he is mentioned in some message text.

How can I query this scenario?

Comment: where in meteor do you want to do this? In a publication or in a method call? If the latter, then you can just trivially breaks this down into two separate queries. The same should work in a publication with only minimally more complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_W2FuAPx8b3)

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      fullName: "User A" 
     } 
  }, 
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "messages",
      let: {
        id: "$_id" //This is what you need to match in the messages collection, kind of variable
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              {
                $expr: { //Matching in sender id
                  $eq: [
                    "$senderId",
                    "$$id"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                $expr: {
                  "$regexMatch": { //matching in messages
                    "input": "$message",
                    "regex": "$$id",
                    
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "senders"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$gt": [//Filtering only the matched results
          {
            "$size": "$senders"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

To add filtering,  you can add a `match` stage before lookup as below

```
{
  $match: {
    fullName: "User A" 
  } 
}
```

Note, mongo is case sensitive db. Updated [sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4-gLgqkiMwV)

Comment: What if users are store on different remote server on SSO?

Comment: You can to store the data in a cluster or single server. You need to have users collection in mongo.

Comment: This solution doesn't seems to be working, also I cant see search criteria in query

Comment: I have mentioned the search criteria in question: "Now here I want to search: User A, so I should get those message in which User A is involved in any way, either he is a sender or he is mentioned in some message text."

Comment: Can you please update your original answer too, so that anyone can get help from that easily. Thanks

Comment: The result is not correct still, because I searched User A, and its giving me records of User C as well. Something isn't right

Comment: It works. Please chekc [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4-gLgqkiMwV)